# Auto Tag Movie Files after Watching

Tags: windows, powershell, tags

I would like to automatically add a tag of 'watched' to my movies after I have watched them, so I can keep track of the ones I haven't seen yet. Right now, I have two folders 'Unwatched' and 'Watched' that I have to manually move movies between.

The lazy developer in me would rather spend a couple hours programming a script to do this for me instead of the manual labor of moving the files for a couple seconds. I have read briefly on the internet about getMetadata for Powershell, but I'm still in the dark about this method. Is there good documentation on Powershell and all of it's functions? Will this do what I want it to do?

An advanced feature I would like is it to tell how long I have played the file for. Sometimes I open a movie file to check the quality, and close it immediately. I usually use VLC on Windows 7 (64 bit) but if this can be done easier when I watch movies in WMP, I will be open to that.

Comment: [link]http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2011/01/07/organizing-videos-and-music.aspx[/link] - Should hopefully help me in getting and setting the file properties. I still need definite help in auto-trigger this would-be script after a I watch a movie.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be simple!

In an ideal world, what you want (if I understand it) it so have your media player automatically mark a video as viewed in it's metadata. There are really two separate puzzles here - the first is how to get your media player to run a script after you finish watching a video and second how to get the video meta-data updated.

I am not sure if any media player has the ability to run a script after a video is finished. I suppose you could dive deep down deep and write your own media player, using something like Silverlight to do the hard stuff. I wish you luck! :-)

A simpler say might be to use a PowerShell function along the lines of:

```
Show-Video {
  param ( $filetoplay,
       [switch] $tag)

# play the video
  mediaplayer $filetoplay # check with your media player for details on how to call it

# when we're done:
  If ($tag) {Update-Metadata -file $filetoplay}

}
```

You's want to tidy this up, add some error checking, etc. But you get the idea.

The second question is how to update the metadata. Metadata is data about data. The data in question is an AVI (or whatever the media), the metadata is information about that AVI.
Metadata is added to a media file, typically at the start of the file. Your challenge will be to open up that metadata, and update it in a way that media player, et al, can understand it!

I found a cool post by Joel that explains how to do it- http://huddledmasses.org/editing-media-tags-from-powershell/. It requires an external library (TabLib Sharp - download from: http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp). I am not sure if there is a 'watched'/'unwatched' metadata item you can use but hopefully this will get your started.

Comment: Yes, I definitely realize the two, separate challenges that need to be overcome. Could I somehow have double-clicking the file open a powershell script that gets the file passed to it, and starts a timer, then launches the file in a media player, and then stop the timer when the file is done playing? Is this what you are describing above? Also, I was hoping to use the tag field that comes built in to Windows 7 (http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/tag-your-files-for-easier-searches-in-windows-7/4024). The watched flags could be contained in there.

Answer (score 0):

Using tag based file system is recommended.

```
Some of those are:
https://www.tagspaces.org/
https://www.tagsistant.net/
```

so you can tag the file whenever you watched a video.
This is the future file system.
Windows already has this feature inbuilt.